# Element innerHTML getting rid of event listeners

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, nodelist

I have a function for adding buttons to a page.

```
var count = 0;

function createOnclickFunction(number)
{
    return function()
    {
        alert("This is button number " + number);
    }
}

function addButton(data)
{
    var newbutton = "..." //creates string from data

    var element = document.getElementById("mydiv");
    var children = element.children;

    element.innerHTML = newbutton + element.innerHTML;

    var currentCount = count;
    children[0].onclick = createOnclickFunction(currentCount)

    count++;
}
```

It basically creates a button into the html based off some data.

Every time I add a button, I would like it to be added to the start of div `#mydiv`, and since newbutton is also not an `Element`, but a `String`, I have to modify the innerHtml to add it to the start of `#mydiv`.

Afterwards, I must get the element (to add an onclick), by getting the first child of `#mydiv`.

However, after adding a second button to my page, the first button onclick no longer works.

If I modify my code to only add one button, everything works fine.

So now, only the top button (the latest added button), can be clicked.

How can I fix this?

I've also tried to use `element.firstChild` instead of `element.children[0]`.

Thanks in advance everyone!

**EDIT:**

Here is a jsfiddle: ( as you can see the only button that works is `stackoverflow` )

https://jsfiddle.net/7c7gtL26/

Comment: Never use `innerHTML` to insert contents. And your code is wrong, there is no way "it works fine" at the beginning.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for the issue?

Comment: @Oriol Does this affect it though?

Comment: @PrashantPalikhe Ok.

Comment: Look at using `addEventListener` instead of setting `onclick`.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Same problem. Event listeners are removed when `innerHTML` is reparsed.

Comment: I never actually took that into consideration !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems you misunderstood the problem. The problem is that you are overwriting `innerHTML` in order to insert contents.

**Never use `innerHTML` to insert contents**. It will remove all the internal data, like event listeners. This is what happens here.

If you want to prepend some HTML string, use `insertAdjacentHTML`:

```js
var count = 0;
function createOnclickFunction(number) {
  return function() {
    alert("This is button number " + number);
  }
}
function addButton(data) {
  var newbutton = "<button>Click me</button>" //creates string from data
  var element = document.getElementById("mydiv");
  element.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', newbutton);
  var children = element.children;
  children[0].onclick = createOnclickFunction(count)
  count++;
}
addButton();
addButton();
addButton();
```

```html
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a million! I never took into consideration, the fact that by modifying the innerHTML, it would overwrite the existing buttons too.