# How can I get the click event inside an innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I've this layout that was created dynamically:

```js
for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  document.querySelector('.card-body').innerHTML += `<div class="row" id="img_div">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 text-center">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/120x80" alt="prewiew" width="120" height="80">
        </div>
        <div id="text_div" class="col-12 text-sm-center col-sm-12 text-md-left col-md-6">
        <h4 class="name"><a href="#" id="title` + i + `">Name</a></h4>
          <h4>
            <small>state</small>
          </h4>
          <h4>
            <small>city</small>
          </h4>
          <h4>
            <small>zip</small>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 text-sm-center col-md-4 text-md-right row">
        </div>
      </div>
     `
  document.getElementById("title" + i).addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(i)
  });
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="card-body">
  <!-- person -->
</div>
```

And I want to get the event click on each `h4 class="name"` and show a log with the number `i` related.

However, `console.log` shows only the last `i` related (`i=9` in this case), and doesn't work with the other `i` numbers. Why does this happen? What do I have to do?

Comment: Maybe use [Document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) instead of passing html-string & you'll have a much easier time & i think you'll end up with better code in the end.

Comment: you''ll have to loop through your nodes again and attach an event you cannot attach into a string

Comment: Nice question, it's kinda tricky for sure, I think it might be possible to attatch an event post rendering.. For example after your `for` loop calling a method to apply events to those elements, but I don't know. will jsFiddle to test.

Comment: Created a delegated event handler for `.card-body` and check if the element (`target`) is an anchor with and ID that starts with `title`.

Comment: Ah, just about to post an answer. Voted to reopen. Closures aren't necessary, the problem is `innerHTML += ...` killing the previously set event listeners, not the closure. Use `document.createElement` instead. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38361875/element-innerhtml-getting-rid-of-event-listeners)

Comment: You are attaching the event listener inside the loop. You loose the event listener when you recreate the elements. 2 solutions: move the creation of the event listeners outside the first loop, or instead of building the entire innerhtml, build each div and append it to the dom.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`innerHTML` redraws the full html, as a result all the previously attached events are lost. Use [`insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

```js
for(let i=1;i<10;i++){
    document.querySelector('.card-body').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',`<div class="row" id="img_div">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 text-center">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/120x80" alt="prewiew" width="120" height="80">
        </div>
        <div id="text_div" class="col-12 text-sm-center col-sm-12 text-md-left col-md-6">
        <h4 class="name"><a href="#" id="title`+i+`">Name</a></h4>
          <h4>
            <small>state</small>
          </h4>
          <h4>
            <small>city</small>
          </h4>
          <h4>
            <small>zip</small>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 text-sm-center col-md-4 text-md-right row">
        </div>
      </div>
     `);
   document.getElementById("title"+i).addEventListener('click', function () {
    console.log(i)
  });
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="card-body">
<!-- person -->
</div>
```

Comment: Wow.. I've been messing around with simular things and never once came accross `insertAdjacentHTML` - Everydays a schoolday, really nice.

Comment: @ggorlen I kinda agree on the perf area out of interest would using the class `name` and attatching the event to just that class while passing through the element (or maybe just reading from the event itself) be more efficient ?

Comment: Definitely worth a benchmark, I can't think of anything better to do tonight! :)

Answer (score 9):

Using `+=` on `innerHTML` destroys event listeners on the elements inside the HTML. Using [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) ensures event listeners are preserved after appending children to a container.

Here's a minimal, complete example:

```js
for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  const anchor = document.createElement("a");
  document.body.appendChild(anchor);
  anchor.id = "title" + i;
  anchor.href = "#";
  anchor.textContent = "link " + i;
  document.getElementById("title" + i)
    .addEventListener("click", e => console.log(i));
}
```

```css
a {
  margin-left: 0.3em;
}
```

Of course, the `document.getElementById` isn't necessary here since we just created the object in the loop block. This approach might help avoid generating ids dynamically, which seems like an antipattern.

```js
for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  const anchor = document.createElement("a");
  document.body.appendChild(anchor);    
  anchor.href = "#";
  anchor.textContent = "link " + i;
  anchor.addEventListener("click", e => console.log(i));
}
```

```css
a {
  margin-left: 0.3em;
}
```

If you have arbitrary chunks of stringified HTML as in your example, you can use `createElement("div")`, set its `innerHTML` once to the chunk and add listeners as needed. Then append the divs as children of your container element.

```js
for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  const rawHTML = `<div><a href="#" id="link-${i}">link ${i}</a></div>`;
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  document.body.appendChild(div);
  div.href = "#";
  div.innerHTML = rawHTML;
  div.querySelector(`#link-${i}`)
    .addEventListener("click", e => console.log(i));
}
```

Other approaches include appending to the `innerHTML` but providing a class name on the links, then using a `document.querySelectorAll(className)` after the HTML is built to add listeners to each link, or using [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) to add a listener to the parent.

As a final note, usually styled `<button>` elements are preferred over links that have a no-action `#` href.

Comment: This is the approach I was considering, and I would hands down give this the solution, but the other answer is great too.

Comment: Thanks for de answer, but i tried to build the layout with createElement and i was unsuccessful

Comment: No problem. Hopefully you realize if you have a big chunk of HTML, you can create a root element container like a `<div>`, then `div.innerHTML += yourHugeChunkOfHTML`. So there's no reason this shouldn't work for any use case.

Comment: I will try to build this layout with your recommendation, I am afraid to use "document.getElementById" several times and slow the performance