# How can I overwrite a portion of an element's text without affecting the rest of the element and any event listeners

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, event-listener, robohelp

I have this code that gets created automatically by Adoboe's RoboHelp 2017 into my HTML5 generated help file:

```
<object id="MapCtrl" classid="CLSID:A8ECFBF5-08CC-4065-BD74-0FAD1EA61317" data-rhtags="1" class="" width="1" height="1">
</object>
<p style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12pt;font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;text-decoration: none;" data-rhtags="1" class="" align="left">In&nbsp;this&nbsp;Topic&nbsp;<a class="dropspot" href="javascript:TextPopup(this)" id="MTHotSpot46267"><span class="MTText" style="display: none;">Show</span><span class="MTText">Hide</span></a></p>
```

I'm trying to use javascript to dynamically modify instances of the `In&nbsp;this&nbsp;Topic&nbsp;` text with a localized string without affecting the Show / Hide links in the anchor tags.

Here's my current attempt:

```
function localizeMiniTOC(){
    const minitoc = document.querySelector('#MapCtrl + p');
    const text = minitoc.textContent;
    console.log (typeof text);
    console.log(text.includes('In\xa0this\xa0Topic'));
    if (text.includes('In\xa0this\xa0Topic') === true){
        let html = minitoc.innerHTML;
        linkStart = html.indexOf('<a');
        remaining = html.substring(linkStart,html.length);
        minitoc.innerHTML = 'En Este Tema ' + remaining;
    }
}
```

This does change the text, but the problem I'm having, is that this also destroys the event listener that RoboHelp creates. For example, here's what the original Firefox Inspector looks like before my above code.

Notice there's this event listener:
[image]

Here's what it looks like after my above code above.

There's now no event listener:
[image]

I did some research today, and I understand from this link that using .innerHTML "removes internal data, like event listeners":
[Element innerHTML getting rid of event listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38361875/element-innerhtml-getting-rid-of-event-listeners)

But I can't seem to figure out a different way to **overwrite** the text before the anchor tag, yet leave the Show / Hide links and event listener unscathed.

Other things I've tried:

- Based on this page ([Is it possible to append to innerHTML without destroying descendants' event listeners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595808/is-it-possible-to-append-to-innerhtml-without-destroying-descendants-event-list)
  ), I've tried to use .insertAdjacentHTML(), but it didn't work either:

```
minitoc.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin','<p>En\xa0Este\xa0Tema\xa0' + remaining + '</p>');
```

(The example in the linked page shows how to do this by appending to an existing element, but I need to overwrite the text leading up to the anchor tag, not append to the element.)

- I've tried to use .setAttribute to recreate the onclick event:
  `minitoc.setAttribute('onClick()',TextPopup('MTHotSpot46267'));`
- I've tried to recreate the event listener but that didn't work either:
  `minitoc.addEventListener('click', TextPopup('MTHotSpot46267'));`

All the examples online seem to deal with appending or prepending, not overwriting text.

How can I dynamically overwrite the `In&nbsp;this&nbsp;Topic&nbsp;` text with a localized string without affecting the Show / Hide links and the event listener on those links?

Comment: Just use delegated events. That technique exists (and is considered best practice) precisely for solving this type of problem: binding a listener to all current and future dynamic children. You bind to the closest stable (non-dynamic) parent. And all current and future children will work because the event bubbles to the non-dynamic parent, which has the event. Not to mention the performance gain, in cases where you have thousands of children: you replace thousands of listeners with only one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps there's not a way to *overwrite* the text without nuking the event handler, but I did manage to fix my code so that it now at least adds the event handler back on after the `minitoc.innerHTML = 'En Este Tema ' + remaining;` line rewrites my paragraph.

Here's my updated function:

```
function localizeMiniTOC(){
    const minitoc = document.querySelector('#MapCtrl + p');
    const anchor = document.querySelector('#MapCtrl + p > a');
    const text = minitoc.textContent;
    if (text.includes('In\xa0this\xa0Topic') === true){
        let html = minitoc.innerHTML;
        linkStart = html.indexOf('<a');
        remaining = html.substring(linkStart,html.length);
        if (anchor.id.includes('MTHotSpot') === true){
            minitoc.innerHTML = 'En Este Tema ' + remaining;
            minitoc.addEventListener('click', function(e){
                if (e.target.tagName === 'SPAN' && e.target.className==="MTText"){
                    TextPopup(anchor.id);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that I had an error in my original attempted workaround to add the event listener back in. In this incorrect code, I had neglected to call the function properly in the second parameter:

```
minitoc.addEventListener('click', TextPopup('MTHotSpot46267'));
```

Here's the fixed code for that (taken from my updated function):

```
minitoc.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  if (e.target.tagName === 'SPAN' && e.target.className==="MTText"){
  TextPopup(anchor.id);
}
```

This results in the event listener getting added to the paragraph and then it was just a matter of making sure I was clicking on the span tag before running the TextPopup function.

In this pic, you can see the added event:
[image: Inspector showing the added event]